# Is to "tell off" a particularly British expression?

Tags: american-english, british-english, phrasal-verbs

I'm translating a short story from Spanish into English. A small child says (literally):

> Why don’t we knock?” I asked. “They’re gonna tell us off.”

(The Spanish is: *Nos van a regañar.*) I've already translated the story into a mostly American English and would like to keep that register, but can't think of another expression to use.

Is "to tell off" a normal, acceptable American expression, or is it specifically British?

Comment: I doubt a child would use the expression "tell off". I'd suggest "They're going to yell at us", which does not imply actual yelling but scolding.

Comment: @StoneyB Convert to answer.

Comment: I think "give out to" is uniquely Irish, but "tell off" is more widely used.

Comment: @StoneyB: I disagree - *to tell **off*** is a common verb form in childrens' speech. Not so much in adult speech - I'm sure any Brit would agree *"You'll get told off!"* is much more likely to be said by a child rather than an adult.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  I should have made it clear that I was speaking specifically of AE usage, which OP was asking about.

Comment: @StoneyB: It's true OP asks about American usage, but that's because he doesn't know *what* it is. I'm pretty certain this particular expression is universal children's English of recent decades.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  I disagree. It's hard to know where to look for meaningful statistics, but even among adults I feel that *tell off* is relatively rare on my side of the pond. FWIW, NGrams confirms this: the most dramatic example is a comparison of "get told off for" and "get yelled at for" in BE and AE.

Comment: @StoneyB: I don't know why you say *"**even** among adult speakers"*, since it's almost entirely a *childish* usage (that seems to have got started in the 50s). But for what it's worth, [this NGram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=told+off+for+not&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=6&smoothing=3) proves pretty conclusively that it's essentially British (*"told off for **not**"* will invariably be the *admonish* sense, not *assign*). Usage in the American corpus is too low to even graph, so it's probably fair to say it's not a *"normal, acceptable American expression"*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  I say "even &c" because that's all you can justify from NGrams. I think we're in agreement otherwise; my original statement was intended to convey that no Amurrican kid would say "tell off"; some adults might.

Comment: @StoneyB: Yes, I think we are in agreement. I'll leave my second comment in there, but I'm in no doubt now that I was wrong to say it's *universal* children's English. Interestingly though, the earliest unambiguous citation I've been able to find is this atypically early [1941 **American**](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22told%20off%20for%20not%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1940,cd_max:1952&lr=lang_en) instance (where the fact that it's "quotated" clearly suggests it wasn't familiar to many at the time).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Tell us off* is an American idiom. However it is much less frequently used in [American literature](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tell%20us%20off&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=5&smoothing=3) than in [British literature](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tell%20us%20off&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=6&smoothing=3).

As noted by StoneyB, young children in the US would be very unlikely to use the phrase. In addition to his *yell at us*, young children might say

> We'll get in trouble
>   or
>   We're gonna get it

Comment: It's not an *American* idiom - it's an ***English*** idiom. I'm not sure exactly why, but your NGrams are misleading. Apart from anything else, I don't think *to tell off* in the sense of *to reprimand* goes back more than a few decades, so there's no point including stuff from 1800 onwards - you should probably restrict yourself to usage from 1970 onwards.

Comment: @FumbleFingers We know it is an *English* idom, but the question was whether it is also an *American* idiom. The ngrams are for tell *us* off, but there are clearly non reprimand uses. I do agree that recent usage is more to the point, so a time restricted analysis makes sense. Google books caries it back to at least [1959](http://books.google.com/books?id=xD5PAAAAYAAJ&q=%22tell+us+off%22&dq=%22tell+us+off%22&source=bl&ots=jcIhCgKlIV&sig=4eaCOmATndHgaiTRaQdWlNceerw&hl=en&sa=X&ei=MXJ9UJ2qOKWG0QGD3IHYBw&ved=0CEwQ6AEwBTgK)

Comment: You've lost me there. I know it's an *English* idiom, because I speak English and it's well-known to me. 7 hours ago I discovered that it's almost exclusively a ***British** English* idiom, which is why I downvoted your answer (because I disagree with the first sentence in it). Whatever - I've now posted my own answer with an NGram that imho conclusively establishes this.

Answer (score 4):

No, it's colloquial American English as well.

A specifically British synonym would be 'to scold', or possibly (and more crudely) 'to bollock'.

Comment: When did you last hear anyone use _scold_?

Comment: @BarrieEngland Scold doesn’t seem too uncommon a word, at least when talking about children and animals.

Comment: @BarrieEngland Last night on Downton Abbey. Also almost every day on parent support websites

Comment: _Downton_ doesn't count because it's of its period. Websites, maybe, but that's not speech. I think it would be unusual to hear, say, 'If you don't stop doing that you'll get scolded' instead of 'If you don't stop doing that you'll get told off.'

Comment: Indeed - I was thinking of scold in an of-its-era use rather than today. @sanschaises doesn't say what time period the short stor is set in. Downton characters wouldn't say "Run, or the master will bollock you" either.

Comment: @BarrieEngland Only because you're deliberately setting the word in an inappropriate context - namely a parent talking to their child. A parent talking to *another* parent might very well say "my son did blah blah and I shouted at him and sent him to his room for the night; do you think I was right to scold him so much?", but I'd equally well expect "do you think I shouldn't have told him off so much?" or "maybe it was unfair of me to give him such a bollocking" or similar.

Answer (score 1):

The truth seems to have been arrived at in comments posted by myself and StoneyB, but here it is as an answer. Firstly, note [this chart of **British** usage](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=told%20off%20for%20not&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=6&smoothing=3) for *"told off for **not**"*...

[image: ng]

...where if you follow the link and switch to the *American* corpus, you'll see that even though this indexes far more books, there aren't even enough results to graph.

I specifically included *"**not**"* in the search string because that ensures almost every instance will be for OP's "scolded" sense. Without that, the results would be swamped by contexts where *"to tell off"* means either to *count off*, or *assign responsibility* (both of which senses are "dated", if not archaic, but still occur often enough to obscure what we're interested in here).

If you leaf through the citations in that link, you'll soon notice that many if not most of them involve young people. It's essentially a post-war British children's slang usage, so the answer to OP's question is: *No - it's **not** a normal, acceptable **American** expression*.

Although I'm not American, and therefore probably shouldn't pronounce on whether an expression is familiar to Americans, I think it's worth pointing out that (British) ["**Mum** told me off"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22mum%20told%20me%20off%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) gets over 300 hits in Google Books, whereas (American) *"**Mom** told me off"* gets none at all.

Comment: +1  I disagree only 50% with your conclusion--"it's ***not*** a 'normal' American expression, but it ***is*** an expression acceptable to Americans. *Langue v parole*.

Comment: @StoneyB: I've no idea how *langue v parole* relates to this matter - unless you just mean that you would understand the usage, but not produce it yourself. Which is a bit irrelevant when we're talking about what *children* would understand. For what it's worth, British [**Mum** told me off](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22mum+told+me+off%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) gets over 300 hits in Google Books. American *"**Mom** told me off"* gets none at all.

Comment: Exactly. It's in the American lexicon, though little used. It's probably not even in the lexicon of American kids.

Comment: @StoneyB: Couldn't you perhaps disagree only 25% then? You're obviously a more competent speaker than the *average* adult, so it's no surprise *you'd* know of the usage. But it's so obviously *not* significantly used by American children that for OP's purposes we might as well say it's not appropriate to have the (by implication, American) child say it in his story.

Comment: *Tell off* is an [American term](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tell+off). See [also](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/tell-off). It is not very common compared to other terms for the same concept.  *Tell off for not* is not an American term.

Comment: @bib: In fact the evidence strongly suggests the specific form *tell off = reprimand* is a ***British*** idiom, albeit known to *some* Americans. But as explained in my answer, you'd get nowhere attempting to track usage statistics without including something like *...for not* to disambiguate the far more common (esp. in American usage) instances where *tell off* means something else. The fact that you can find a definition in an "American" dictionary proves nothing, since all English dictionaries these days are likely to include both British and American usages.

Comment: I and my circle have been using the phrase *tell off* meaning *reprimand* in the US for my 65 years. As I have said (several times) it is not the *most* common, but it is widely used, is not at all odd, ambiguous or uncomfortable to US speakers. In fact, any meaning other than *reprimand* would seem odd to most US speakers.

Comment: @bib: Perhaps your circle is atypical. How else do you explain the complete absence of *"**Mom** told me off"* in Google Books?

Comment: Check out [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22told+me+off%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&gs_nf=3&tok=ma2RyiShpzjjFhVH9w3uuw&ds=bo&pq=%22told%20me%20off%22&cp=10&gs_id=k&xhr=t&q=%22told+him+off%22&pf=p&tbo=1&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&oq=%22told+him+off%22&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=4b53550b15ee95df&bpcl=35277026&biw=1280&bih=709). Only 800k+ results.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a child would say "They'll scold us". "We'll get told off" is much more likely.

Comment: I agree, but it doesn't seem to relate to the question.

Answer (score 0):

It is a common usage in the US, including among (at least pre-adolescent) children. The phrase that is likely the most universal (by personal experience) for expressing emotion charged, hostile and hostility-tinged, English/non-English, statements of that kind is: (to be) *mad at*. It is a "way of saying" comfortable to all ages.

"Why don't we knock?" (little first person) I asked. "They'll be mad!" (was the reply)

Answer (score 0):

This question was asked and answered quite a while ago, but I think there's another interesting facet to the story so I'm asking this answer.

This *is* an old-fashioned AmE idiom, but with a slightly different meaning than the BrE idiom which would make it inappropriate in the given situation. Specifically, it is used *between adults* (often from someone in a slightly lesser position of power) to express outrage or anger over the other's behavior, especially behavior that had previously gone uncensured; similar to ["give a piece of (my) mind"](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/give-sb-a-piece-of-your-mind). I would, for example, expect to hear it used about a blow-hard co-worker, but not about one's child.

This usage goes back to the middle of the 20th century, at least. An [Ngram of "really told him off"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=really%20told%20him%20off&year_start=1920&year_end=2008&corpus=5&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Creally%20told%20him%20off%3B%2Cc0) in the American corpus finds  usage back to the 1940s, which peaked a couple of decades later and has been gradually fading ever since.
[image]

Interestingly, many of the earliest available examples are from transcripts or reporting, suggesting the idiom may have been in use in spoken language for at least a little while before authors caught up. For example:

> Q: You **really told him off**, didn't you, Bob?
>
> A: Well--
>
> Q: You were mad?
>
> A: I was sore.
>
> Q: And you really let him have it?
>
> A: Yes, sir.
>
> (From the [Decisions and Orders of the National Labor Relations Board](https://books.google.com/books?id=q0DHAAAAMAAJ&q=%22really%20told%20him%20off%22&dq=%22really%20told%20him%20off%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjR4vKcoc_NAhWL5YMKHcH5BtcQ6AEIIDAB), combined snippets)

Switching to the [British corpus and searching "told him off"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=told%20him%20off&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=6&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctold%20him%20off%3B%2Cc0) (the "really" element is common in AmE but not BrE) does turn up a few early examples, notably a [1957 ethnography](https://books.google.com/books?id=Rk3KadLaRssC&pg=PA237&dq=%22told%20him%20off%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj437_NsM_NAhXs6oMKHQmJCBAQ6AEIITAB#v=onepage&q=%22told%20him%20off%22&f=false) that uses the phrase in the American sense. (A tantalizingly early work appears to actually be a more recent translation of the 1910 book.) However, it appears that the American usage may have predated the British.

Examples of the "truth-to-power" sense of the phrase include a 1949 [anecdote](https://books.google.com/books?id=StQjAQAAMAAJ&q=%22really%20told%20him%20off%22&dq=%22really%20told%20him%20off%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjR4vKcoc_NAhWL5YMKHcH5BtcQ6AEIJTAC) about a man who meant to tell off a city official, but accidentally got the man's "innocent wife"; a [1962 review](https://books.google.com/books?id=p0eQtCiQjVMC&pg=PA109&dq=really%20told%20him%20off&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjlt66DqM_NAhXSpYMKHS0cA44Q6AEIKTAC#v=onepage&q=really%20told%20him%20off&f=false) of the play *The Desk Set* (later a Hepburn-Tracy vehicle) which describes three underlings deciding to tell off their boss; a [1975 description](https://books.google.com/books?id=YE5OAQAAIAAJ&q=%22really%20told%20him%20off%22&dq=%22really%20told%20him%20off%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi89av7qM_NAhXIx4MKHQc1APIQ6AEIGzAA) of a wife telling her therapist about "standing up to" her husband and telling him off; a [1988 story](https://books.google.com/books?id=CD1OEopwVocC&q=%22really%20told%20him%20off%22&dq=%22really%20told%20him%20off%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiT9tqzqc_NAhUHzIMKHT_UAQ8Q6AEIKDAD) of a man telling off a doctor over not being allowed in his wife's delivery room; and so on.

None of the examples I looked at were of adults scolding children, or described children speaking (though some of them described younger people doing the telling off).

It is unclear whether there is a direct relationship, and, if there is, how an adult phrase for scolding of peers or bigwigs turned into a children's term for a parental scolding. It seems plausible that an idiom about empowerment would appeal to children, but that's just a guess, and doesn't explain how the power dynamic of the phrase got flipped.